# Questions about News Stand in iOS 5

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, ios5

I am trying to use NewsStand feature in iOS 5 and I have some question about this kind of applications

1-  should I use  In-App Purchases for subscribing the magazines?

2-  What kind of magazine they are ? are they PDF or Website ?

3-  Can I use UIPageController and load a PDF magazine into it ?

thank you .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Apple requires that Newsstand apps offer at least one auto-renewable subscription (this is a type of in-app purchase). If your users have purchased a subscription via some other, external method, you are allow to prompt for this ("enter your username/password" or "enter your existing subscription ID"). But the only type of subscription you're allowed to sell (or even link to) in the app is an In-App Purchase one.
2. Newsstand apps are just apps. They can display whatever you want. Certainly two possibilities are PDFs or websites, but you are not limited to either.
3. Yes, you can use `UIPageViewController`. Yes `UIPageViewController` could, in theory, display pages from a PDF. There's no automatic support for this, though. You'd have to write it.

Comment: Do you know how to create NewsStand app? Is there any tutorial to create such app and publish to app store?

Comment: It's basically the same as creating a regular app. There are only a few things to do differently. One is (optionally) using NewssstandKit to deal with downloads and issue management. The other is implementing auto-renewing subscription In-App purchases. The best tutorials for both those topics is currently the WWDC videos, which are available for free to registered iOS developers at: http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/